# How can I convert a .wav to .mp3 in-memory?

Tags: python, numpy, audioformat

I have a numpy array from a `some.npy` file that contains data of an audio file that is encoded in the `.wav` format.

The `some.npy` was created with `sig = librosa.load(some_wav_file, sr=22050)` and `np.save('some.npy', sig)`.
I want to convert this numpy array as if its content was encoded with `.mp3` instead.

Unfortunately, I am restricted to the use of in-memory file objects for two reasons.

1. I have many `.npy` files. They are cached in advance and it would be highly inefficient to have that much "real" I/O when actually running the application.
2. Conflicting access rights of people who are executing the application on a server.

First, I was looking for a way to convert the data in the numpy array directly, but there seems to be no library function. So is there a simple way to achieve this with in-memory file objects?

**NOTE:** I found this question [How to convert MP3 to WAV in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049572/how-to-convert-mp3-to-wav-in-python) and its solution could be theoretically adapted but this is not in-memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a working solution. This is what I wanted.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
wav = np.load('some.npy')
with io.BytesIO() as inmemoryfile:
        compression_format = 'mp3'
        n_channels = 2 if wav.shape[0] == 2 else 1 # stereo and mono files
        AudioSegment(wav.tobytes(), frame_rate=my_sample_rate, sample_width=wav.dtype.itemsize,
                     channels=n_channels).export(inmemoryfile, format=compression_format)
        wav = np.array(AudioSegment.from_file_using_temporary_files(inmemoryfile)
                       .get_array_of_samples())
```

There exists a wrapper package (*[audiosegment](https://audiosegment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/audiosegment.html)*) with which one could convert the last line to:

```
wav = audiosegment.AudioSegment.to_numpy_array(AudioSegment.from_file_using_temporary_files(inmemoryfile))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write memory using BytesIO, like this:

```
import BytesIO

# Create "in-memory" buffer
memoryBuff = io.BytesIO()
```

And you can read and write MP3 using `pydub` module:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

# Read a file in
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav('stereo_file.wav')

# Write to memory buffer as MP3
sound.export(memoryBuff, format='mp3')
```

Your MP3 data is now available at `memoryBuff.getvalue()`

You can convert between `AudioSegments` and Numpy arrays using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66922265/2836621) answer.

Comment: I couldn't use this directly as I need to work with the numpy data but I have found `audiosegment.from_numpy_array(nparr, framerate)` in an `AudioSegment`-wrapper. My problem is now that `sound.export(memoryBuff, format='mp3')` returns a `bytestr` and not a `numpy` array. I tried numerous ways to convert this to a numpy array (for example `audiosegment.deserialize(bytestr)` and then your suggested `pydub_to_np`) but I get a broad variety of errors. How can I do that? EDIT: for whatever reason, `np.frombuffer(bytestr)` didn't work before.. it works now.

Comment: Sorry, misinformation.  `np.frombuffer(bytestr)` does indeed work but it leads to extremely weird values which is somehow understandable as the bytestring returned by the `.export` call encodes an mp3 file and contains header information etc. which is not interpretable in a reasonable way by `np.frombuffer(bytestr)`. How can I convert that `bytestr` back to a `numpy` array in the right way?