# How to feed a numpy array as audio for whisper model

Tags: python, numpy, openai-whisper, audiosegment

So I want to open an mp3 using AudioSegment, then I want to convert the AudioSegment object to numpy array and use this numpy array as input for whisper model, I followed this question [How to create a numpy array from a pydub AudioSegment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015319/how-to-create-a-numpy-array-from-a-pydub-audiosegment) but non of the result was helpful since I get always error like

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programmi\PythonProjects\whisper_real_time\test\converting_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    result = audio_model.transcribe(arr_copy, language="en", word_timestamps=True,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Programmi\PythonProjects\whisper_real_time\venv\Lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 121, in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, padding=N_SAMPLES)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Programmi\PythonProjects\whisper_real_time\venv\Lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 146, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = F.pad(audio, (0, padding))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at ..\c10\core\impl\alloc_cpu.cpp:72] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 86261939712 bytes.
```

This error is strange because if I provide directly the file like below I get no problems

```
result = audio_model.transcribe("../audio_test_files/1001_IEO_DIS_HI.mp3", language="en", word_timestamps=True,
                                        fp16=torch.cuda.is_available())
```

This is the code I wrote

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np
import whisper
import torch


audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3("../audio_test_files/1001_IEO_DIS_HI.mp3")

dtype = getattr(np, "int{:d}".format(
    audio.sample_width * 8))  # Or could create a mapping: {1: np.int8, 2: np.int16, 4: np.int32, 8: np.int64}
arr = np.ndarray((int(audio.frame_count()), audio.channels), buffer=audio.raw_data, dtype=dtype)
arr_copy = arr.copy()
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(f"Loading whisper...")
audio_model = whisper.load_model("small", download_root="../models",
                                     device=device)
print(f"Transcribing...")
result = audio_model.transcribe(audio=arr_copy, language="en", word_timestamps=True,
                                        fp16=torch.cuda.is_available())  # , initial_prompt=result.get('text', ""))
text = result['text'].strip()
print(text)
```

how can I do it?

--------EDIT--------
I edited the code, and now I use the code below. I don't have the error that I had before but the model seems to don't transcribe correctly. I tested what audio I was passing to the model exporting back the wav file, I played it and there is a lot of noise, I can't understand what they are saying so that's why the model does not transcribe. Are the passage of normalization that I am doing ok?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np
import whisper
import torch

language = "en"
model = "medium"
model_path = "../models"

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(f"Loading whisper {model} model {language}...")
audio_model = whisper.load_model(model, download_root=model_path, device=device)

# load wav file with pydub
audio_path = "20230611-004146_audio_chunk.wav"
audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_path)
#audio_segment = audio_segment.low_pass_filter(1000)
# get sample rate
sample_rate = audio_segment.frame_rate
arr = np.array(audio_segment.get_array_of_samples())
arr_copy = arr.copy()
arr_copy = torch.from_numpy(arr_copy)
arr_copy = arr_copy.to(torch.float32)
# normalize
arr_copy = arr_copy / 32768.0
# to device
arr_copy = arr_copy.to(device)


print(f"Transcribing...")
result = audio_model.transcribe(arr_copy, language=language, fp16=torch.cuda.is_available())
text = result['text'].strip()
print(text)

waveform = arr_copy.cpu().numpy()
audio_segment = AudioSegment(
    waveform.tobytes(),
    frame_rate=sample_rate,
    sample_width=waveform.dtype.itemsize,
    channels=1
)
audio_segment.export("test.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: What `dtype` does your code end up choosing? What is the shape of the numpy array that it is trying to create?

Comment: that is what I'm trying to know about whisper model, I don't know what shape the model wants as input @jared

Comment: Which line is causing the error, the `arr = ...` line?

Comment: @jared yes sorry, I updated the question with the full traceline. Also I added a copy to the code to solve a warning

Comment: If providing the file directly works, why are you trying to put it into an array and pass that?

Comment: because in my program I need to process audio in real time using chunks of audio converted in AudioSegment. I provided this example with an mp3 to show that I can't convert from an AudioSegment object to a numpy array @jared

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember right, internally Whisper operates on 16kHz mono audio segments of 30 seconds. The conversion to the correct format, splitting and padding is handled by `transcribe` function. This is why when you supply the MP3 path it is working correctly.

If you want to supply `numpy` array you need to do the format and sample rate conversion by yourself. I suggest you start by creating a short (say 10 sec) audio clip in `WAV` PCM format. Loading it should provide you an `int16` array of 160000 samples (10sec * 16kHz = 160000). Convert the values to `float32`, and normalize by dividing it by `32768.0`. The result should be accepted by Whisper.

```
audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_path)

# convert to expected format
if audio_segment.frame_rate != 16000: # 16 kHz
    audio_segment = audio_segment.set_frame_rate(16000)
if audio_segment.sample_width != 2:   # int16
    audio_segment = audio_segment.set_sample_width(2)
if audio_segment.channels != 1:       # mono
    audio_segment = audio_segment.set_channels(1)        
arr = np.array(audio_segment.get_array_of_samples())
arr = arr.astype(np.float32)/32768.0

result = audio_model.transcribe(arr, language=language, fp16=torch.cuda.is_available())
print(result['text'])
```

If your original audio is noisy then it is hard to expect good results for transcription.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code as you said, I don't get the error anymore but the model can't transcribe correctly because the audio that I obtain is very noisy. I tested it export back the audio in wav format. Do I normalized the audio in the correct way? can you provide me an example?